# COUNT with condition and join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, conditional-statements

I have dialogs and messages. The goal is to select dialogs and their count of unreaded messages. Table messages has `unread` field to detect it.

I've tried this

```
SELECT *, count(unread) as nums 
FROM dialogs JOIN messages ON dialogs.id=messages.dialog_id  
GROUP BY dialogs.id 
HAVING count(unread) <> 0
```

but always get total count of messages

Comment: Probably MySQL or the * wouldn't work with only grouping by dialogs.id?

Comment: MySQL, forgot to detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "unread" is, as you state, a count of unread messages, then it always has a value, even if zero, and is always included in COUNT(unread).

Try inserting a `WHERE messages.unread != 0`

Comment: Maybe SUM instead of COUNT?  Is Unread a true/false field or can it have any numerical value?  Can you post examples of the source data?

Comment: Can you share the ENUM defintion with the rest of us?

Comment: then try '0' instead of 0 in the WHERE clause -- lol, we can't read your mind

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18644/discussion-between-meliborn-and-exactabox)

Answer (score 1):

Oh!!! Count by messages.id.
Try this:

```
SELECT *, count(messages.id) as nums FROM dialogs  
      JOIN messages ON dialogs.id=messages.dialog_id  
      WHERE messages.unread = 1 
      GROUP BY dialogs.id 
      HAVING nums <> 0
```

An Enum type for messages.unread might need to have it quoted:

```
SELECT *, count(messages.id) as nums FROM dialogs  
      JOIN messages ON dialogs.id=messages.dialog_id  
      WHERE messages.unread = '1' 
      GROUP BY dialogs.id 
      HAVING nums <> 0
```

I'm not sure why you'd create a enum('0','1') though....

Comment: If you take out the dialogs table and join does it work? `SELECT *, count(unread) as nums FROM messages GROUP BY dialogs_id HAVING nums <> 0`

Comment: I should group by dialog.id, if I'll use group by message.id a all messages instead dialogs

Comment: @Meliborn My mistake, see the change, I meant  count messages.id.  I'm assuming unread has a 1 or 0 value

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18643/discussion-between-ray-and-meliborn)

Answer (score 1):

If you say that the table `messages` have a column `unread`, then I don't get why you should count that column, you probably need to sum those values (assuming that there can be more than one record with the same `dialog_id` on that table). So, I would write your query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dialogs D
INNER JOIN (SELECT dialog_id, COUNT(*) AS nums
            FROM messages
            WHERE unread = 1
            GROUP BY dialog_id) M
ON D.id = M.dialog_id  
WHERE M.nums > 0
```

Comment: @Meliborn I don't fully understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry, I got total count of messages instead unreaded messages.

Comment: @Meliborn Are you running the exact same query that is posted now, I updated it a couple of minutes ago

Comment: Yes, I running the last query.

Comment: @Meliborn I don't see how you could be getting those results. Probably I don't really understand your tables structures. You should update your question with that information and probably some test data of what you have and what you want

Comment: @Meliborn Ok, apparently, the `unread` column its a boolean (basically `true` or `false`), so I updated my answer according to that

Comment: Hm, but if I have messages with unread = '0' there are no dialog with this messages in total select, which logic - we set 'where = 1'.